# How is the graph of a Bourbaki function usually written?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, notation, set-theory, terminology

Given a Bourbaki function $f = (F, A, B)$, its *domain* $A$ is often denoted by $\operatorname{dom} f$ and its *codomain*, *range*, or *target*  by $\operatorname{cod} f$ (and sometimes $\operatorname{ran} f$, depending on the author).

What's the typical notation for the function graph of $f$, i.e., for $F$? We already have two destructors ($\operatorname{dom}$ and $\operatorname{cod}$), but a Bourbaki function has three components, so one destructor is missing, or, at least, I have not seen it yet ….

References to literature are overly welcome.

Comment: Why is the codomain well-defined? You can always enlarge it, no?

Comment: If you’re saying $A=\text{dom}(f)$, and $B=\text{cod}(f)$ and asking what goes in the missing blank $F=(?)(f)$, then some ways I’ve seen it written are $\Gamma(f)$ or $\Gamma_f$  or $\text{graph}(f)$ or $\text{Gr}(f)$ etc.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki Purely technically, $(,,)=(',',') \Rightarrow ='$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thx! Any references?

Comment: nothing specific. It’s just stuff I’ve seen all over the place.

Comment: @peek-a-boo If we were to go with $\operatorname{Gr}$, we'd probably also have to capitalize the other two destructors, writing $\operatorname{Dom}$ and $\operatorname{Cod}$. We do not wish to do this at the moment. Have you seen small $\operatorname{gr}$, perhaps?

Comment: if you can imagine a variant, it definitely exists somewhere. I’m all for getting terminology straight, but caps vs non caps? really?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes. Caps vs. non-caps is important to us because we've reserved capital multi-letter identifiers for sorts (= types) in a sorted logic. By the way, for such basic destructors, we don't use the parens because, technically speaking, $\operatorname{dom}$, $\operatorname{cod}$, as well as other well-known operators, such as $\operatorname{sup}$, $\operatorname{lfp}$, $\operatorname{min}$, …, are not functions themselves (because their domains are NOT sets), so ${\cdot}({\cdot})$ as function application is questionable.

Comment: this is not a "Bourbaki function", it is just the standard definition of a mathematical function

Comment: @Masacroso It's *not* THE but A standard definition. Some set-theory folks define a function as a left-total and right-unique relation. So when you go into set-theoretical details, you better specify which definitions you take.

Comment: Cross-posted at Mathoverflow: this is something you should not do (simultaneously) to prevent duplication of efforts.